# What kind of application is needed to undergo third-party security assessment?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

Our application wants to access GmailAPI and need some restricted scopes.
When I went through [OAuth API Verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914), I found this sentence.

> Apps that request restricted scopes.........One of these additional requirements is that if the app accesses or has the capability to access Google user data from or through a server, the system must undergo an independent, third-party security assessment.

My question is

- 1. What kind of data access needs third-party security assessment (among applications using restricted scope)?
- 2. Does our application needs third-party security assessment?

Our application needs scopes of

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels

Our application use these scopes to

- fetch user's emails which is labeled with our application specific labels.
- send mail with our application specific labels.
- create filter to categorize mail with our application specific labels.

Comment: This seems like a question you need to ask Google directly.  If you thought posting here would contact them, you're mistaken.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge

Since Gmail Official API Document leads me here, I think it was not mistaken, but a proper way.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support?hl=ja

Comment: @moss SO has little control as to what a Third party website points to them.  The local sewing circle could link here it doesn't mean its official sewing support.  SO is not owned by Google, it is not maned by Google employees waiting to answer your questions.   We are simple developers like yourself willing to share our experience.

Comment: Ok, I understand the situation of SO, and I also understand this is not a Google Support Desk.

I totally respect and appreciate to the kind and dedicated support of you guys. I really thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Please note SO is NOT google support google engineers will rarely respond to a question like this if they respond at all.

> 1. What kind of data access needs third-party security assessment (among applications using restricted scope)?

Directly from the documentation [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)

> Apps that request sensitive scopes must verify that they follow Google’s API [Services User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy) and will not have to undergo an independent, third-party security assessment. This sensitive scopes verification process typically takes 3-5 business days to complete.

From [Services User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy)

> Google API Services, including Google Sign-In, are part of an authentication and authorization framework that gives you, the developer, the ability to connect directly with Google users when you would like to request access to Google user data.

In a nutshell any app accessing private user data has the potential of needing third party security assessment.   However gmail scopes almost always require assmenssment

2. Does our application needs third-party security assessment?

You appear to be using several gmail scopes, if you check the [Services User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy) it states that gmail scopes are of conserve due to potential security risks.

[image]

IMO being that you are using Gmail scopes I would expect you to need an assessment.

Comment: @DalmTo

Thank you for your kind advice. This answer helps me a lot.

> In a nutshell any app accessing private user data has the potential of needing third party security assessment. However gmail scopes almost always require assmenssment

It seems that there's no way but take an assessment. I try to do it.

Comment: Heads up the last information i saw says an assessment costs between $15k and $75k.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information!